# "it would take me 1–2 seconds"

Tags: grammar, past-tense, infinitives

or "it would took me 1–2 seconds"?

Comment: Nice to see the en dash used correctly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"It would take me 1-2 seconds" is correct. It takes the infinitive.

Answer (score 5):

- Once in the past, it **took** me one or two seconds.
- Previously, it **has taken** me one or two seconds (at most …).
- So far, it **has taken** me one or two seconds (and may take longer to complete).
- Currently, it **takes** me one or two seconds (every time, to complete).
- In the future, it **will take** me one or two seconds.
- If I had done it yesterday, it **would have taken** me one or two seconds.
- If I did it tommorrow, it **would take** me one or two seconds.

Comment: So, "took" never follows any auxiliary in standard English.

Comment: not too sure about 'standard' English - but I remember growing up in the north of England with people saying things like "it could have took me forever"

Comment: Yeah worth noting that HorusKol is right and that's common in many northern English dialects - but it's not "real" academically

Answer (score 2):

If you are wanting to indicate how long it would have taken you to complete a task that has already been completed:

> It took Stephen 10 seconds to get the right answer, but it would have taken me 1 or 2 seconds.